# For loop to create a sequence of blocks of repeated ids

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, repeat

I'm trying to create a new id (id_2 in the data below)  based on a category column (0/1). If the category is 0 I just need an NA, if this is 1, then I need to repeat 1 for the first group of  '1s', then 2 for the second group of '1s' and so on. I need to do it separately for each id_1.

Below is an example of my data, my attempt to do it and the output.
I also tried to include a while loop in the function, but this didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated.

- My data

  ```
    id_1  category    id_2
       1  NA  NA
       1  1   1
       1  1   1
       1  1   1
       1  1   1
       1  0   NA
       1  1   2
       1  1   2
       1  1   2
       1  0   NA
       1  0   NA
       1  1   3
       1  1   3
       1  1   3
       1  0   NA
       2  0   NA
       2  1   1
       2  1   1
       2  0   NA
       2  0   NA
       2  0   NA
       2  1   2
       2  1   2
       2  1   2
       2  1   2
       3  1   1
       3  1   1
       3  1   1
       3  1   1
       3  0   NA
       3  1   2
       3  1   2
       3  0   NA
       3  0   NA
       3  1   3
       3  1   3
       4  0   NA
       4  1   1
       4  1   1
       4  1   1
       4  0   NA
       5  1   1
       5  1   1
       5  1   1
  ```
- My code

  ```
  my_function <- function(df){
  out <- vector()
  out_2 <- list()
  for(k in unique(df$id_1)){
   dat <- df[df$id_1 == k,]
   i <- 0
   #while(i <= dim(dat)[1]){
    i <- i+1
   for(j in 3: dim(dat)[1]-1){
     out[j] <- (ifelse(dat[j-1, 2] == 1, 
                           ifelse(dat[j, 2] == 1, i, NA),    # yes 1st     ifelse()
                           ifelse(dat[j, 2] == 1, i+1, NA))) # no 1st ifelse()
     out_2[[k]] <- out
     }
   #}
  }
  return(out_2)
  }
  ```
- The output

  ```
  #[[1]]
  #[1] NA NA  1  1  1 NA  2  1  1 NA NA  2  1  1

  #[[2]]
  #[1] NA  2  1 NA NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA  2  1  1

  #[[3]]
  #[1] NA  1  1  1 NA  2  1 NA NA  2 NA  2  1  1

  #[[4]]
  #[1] NA  2  1  1 NA  2  1 NA NA  2 NA  2  1  1

  #[[5]]
  # [1] NA  1  1  1 NA  2  1 NA NA  2 NA  2  1  1
  ```

Comment: I guess for 'id_1' 4 and 5, the values should be 1.

Comment: yes, you're right @akrun. Now corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id_1', we apply the run-length-id function (`rleid`) to the logical `vector` (`category ==0 & !is.na(category)`), convert the 0s' to NA (`NA^(!i1)*i1)`), then change it to `factor` and get the `numeric` encoding, assign (`:=`) it as 'id_new' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, id_new := {
        i1 <- category*rleid(category==0 & !is.na(category))
         as.numeric(factor(NA^(!i1)*i1))},
         by = id_1]
df1
#    id_1 category id_2 id_new
# 1:    1       NA   NA     NA
# 2:    1        1    1      1
# 3:    1        1    1      1
# 4:    1        1    1      1
# 5:    1        1    1      1
# 6:    1        0   NA     NA
# 7:    1        1    2      2
# 8:    1        1    2      2
# 9:    1        1    2      2
#10:    1        0   NA     NA
#11:    1        0   NA     NA
#12:    1        1    3      3
#13:    1        1    3      3
#14:    1        1    3      3
#15:    1        0   NA     NA
#16:    2        0   NA     NA
#17:    2        1    1      1
#18:    2        1    1      1
#19:    2        0   NA     NA
#20:    2        0   NA     NA
#21:    2        0   NA     NA
#22:    2        1    2      2
#23:    2        1    2      2
#24:    2        1    2      2
#25:    2        1    2      2
#26:    3        1    1      1
#27:    3        1    1      1
#28:    3        1    1      1
#29:    3        1    1      1
#30:    3        0   NA     NA
#31:    3        1    2      2
#32:    3        1    2      2
#33:    3        0   NA     NA
#34:    3        0   NA     NA
#35:    3        1    3      3
#36:    3        1    3      3
#37:    4        0   NA     NA
#38:    4        1    1      1
#39:    4        1    1      1
#40:    4        1    1      1
#41:    4        0   NA     NA
#42:    5        1    1      1
#43:    5        1    1      1
#44:    5        1    1      1
```

Comment: Fantastic! this worked perfectly and just a few lines were needed. I guess here the key functions are setDT() and rleid(), but I'll also need to understand the syntax within of the as.numeric() function. Thanks a lot @akrun

Comment: @Rafael Thanks, I will update with some descriptions

Comment: Great! thanks @akrun for the description, it is very helpful.